# How can I divide a vector by a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inverse

I am trying to go backwards through a neural network. I have an output and I want to see what input would lead to that output. To go forwards I start with a vector and multiply by a matrix and then multiply that resulting matrix by a vector and so on. To go back I need to divide the solution vector by a series of matrices. I tried calculating the pseudo-inverse of the matrices using Julia's built in function and multiplying but the solution was quite far off from where it should have been. Is there a way to do this more precisely? I know its not an easy problem but I would imagine there must be a way to do this with relatively small (4x7) matrices.

Edit* If my state vector is **x** then going forward means calculating **Ax** for some **A**.

Comment: It would help if you could be more precise about what's going on here.  If your current state vector is $x$, does "going forward" mean calculating $Ax$ for some $A$?

Comment: It is worth noting that in all situations regarding fat matrices (more columns than rows), the process $x \mapsto Ax$ is not inherently reversible.  In particular, there are multiple (infinitely many) vectors $x$ that would progress to the same next vector $Ax$.  The pseudo-inverse $A^\dagger (Ax)$ just gives you one of the many options (in a sense, it selects the "best option").

Comment: I am aware that it is not inherently reversible but I was wondering if I could get at least one precise solution or perhaps the space of solutions. Only one layer is represented by a fat matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example to illustrate that this is not just difficult, but impossible (without more constraints/information).

Suppose that our first (column-) vector $x$ was $(3,-1,2)$.  Let's take the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0}
$$
then the output $Ax$ is going to be the smaller vector $Ax = (3,-1)$.

Suppose, then, that we want to reverse this process.  That is, we know that the output is $Ax = (3,-1),$ and we want to figure out which vector $x$ this came from.  If we solved the associated system of equations for $x$, we would find that the solution
$$
x = (3,-1,t)
$$
will work for **any** value of $t$.  If you use the pseudo-inverse, you would pick out the smallest among these answers (i.e. vector with the shortest Pythagorean length), namely
$$
x = A^\dagger (Ax) = (3,-1,0)
$$
which doesn't necessarily match your original input.